# How to stop displaying the Cypress Hooks in Cypress logs and reports

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Assuming I am working with 2 test files. In one of the step definition files, I implemented some Hooks in them for example:

Test1:

```
import {
    Given,
    When,
    Then
} from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

Given ("I visit Wikipedia", () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.wikipedia.org');
});
When ("I search something", () => {
    cy.get("input[type='search']").type('Music');
    cy.get("button[type='submit']").click();
});
Then ("I check if it is there", () => {
    cy.get('.mw-page-title-main').contains('Music')
});
```

Test2:

```
import {
    Given,
    When,
    Then,
    Before,
    After
} from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

Before(() => {
    cy.log('Execeuted BEFORE Scenario in Test 2');
});

After(() => {
    cy.log('Execeuted AFTER Scenario in Test 2');
});
Given ("I visit my uncle", () => {
    cy.log("Going to see uncle")
});
When ("I tell him stories", () => {
    cy.log("He laughs at my stories")
});
Then ("I eat his food", () => {
    cy.log('He is happy and gives me food');
});
```

When I run Test1, I get the Before and After Hooks being logged in my test and report even though they are not defined in Test1.[image]

The reason why this is an issue for me is because if I am working on a large project with many files with different hooks, these will all be logged in my report which I don't want. I wish to have only the hooks in the test that is being called to be displayed.

Please is there a way of implementing Before and After Hooks without it logging if the test being run does not have them? Thanks.

I am using Cypress v10.11.0, [cucumber by Badeball](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor) and [multiple-cucumber-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter)

I tried running what I have in the hooks in each scenario and deleted the hooks, to avoid the Hooks from being logged but it feels reduntant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use tags for it. Here are some dummy code snippet for your understanding:

```
const {After, Before} = require('@cucumber/cucumber') // you can use the cypress cucumber preprocessor here

Before({tags: "@foo and @bar"}, function () {
  // This hook will be executed before scenarios tagged with @foo and @bar
});

Before({tags: "@foo or @bar"}, function () {
  // This hook will be executed before scenarios tagged with @foo or @bar
});
```

For reference, please see the documentation:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/hooks.md

Comment: Thank you this worked for me and the best solution I could find so far.